# SQL - Create extra column using a sum condition based on another column by category

Tags: sql, database, ssms

I have a SQL table that looks like this:

| ID | account | amount | paid |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 | 100 | 50 |
| 2 | 1 | 100 | 50 |
| 3 | 2 | 10 | 3 |
| 4 | 3 | 20 | 5 |
| 5 | 3 | 20 | 15 |
| 6 | 4 | 50 | 20 |

I want to add a extra column that can be used to check if the account column is completely paid off. A yes for paid and no for not full payment. To do this I want to check if the paid column total adds up to it's amount column for each account.
In other words the results should look something like this:

| ID | account | amount | paid | Payment Complete |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 | 100 | 50 | YES |
| 2 | 1 | 100 | 50 | YES |
| 3 | 2 | 10 | 3 | NO |
| 4 | 3 | 20 | 5 | YES |
| 5 | 3 | 20 | 15 | YES |
| 6 | 4 | 50 | 20 | NO |

How can I create this extra column in SQL?

Comment: Please tag your question with the DBMS that you are using

Comment: Short answer:  add this as a column: to your select `case when sum(paid) over (partition by account) = amount then 'YES' else 'NO' end as PaymentComplete`

Comment: You didn't explain what you want to have happen if they "Over pay"  so over payments come back as "No" as well since they must EXACTLY Match for it to be payment complete.

Answer (score 0):

You just want to use a window function to sum the paid amount and then compare it to the amount by account I think.  (Assuming MS SQL Server givne SSMS is listed but it may not be... however, if the RDBMS supports window functions this shoudl work....)

[Demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/vzPfe7Iq)

```
--THE CTE is to get sample data/table to play with.
WITH CTE AS (
select 1 id,    1 account,  100 amount, 50 paid UNION ALL
select 2,   1,  100,    50 UNION ALL
select 3,   2,  10, 3 UNION ALL
select 4,   3,  20, 5 UNION ALL
select 5,   3,  20, 15 UNION ALL
select 6,   4,  50, 20)

--This is the heart of what you want: 

SELECT *
    , case when sum(paid) over (partition by account) = amount 
      then 'YES' 
      else 'NO' end as PaymentComplete
FROM CTE
```

Resulting in:

```
+----+---------+--------+------+-----------------+
| id | account | amount | paid | PaymentComplete |
+----+---------+--------+------+-----------------+
|  2 |       1 |    100 |   50 | YES             |
|  1 |       1 |    100 |   50 | YES             |
|  3 |       2 |     10 |    3 | NO              |
|  5 |       3 |     20 |   15 | YES             |
|  4 |       3 |     20 |    5 | YES             |
|  6 |       4 |     50 |   20 | NO              |
+----+---------+--------+------+-----------------+
```

Note: overpayments are treated the same as underpayments and come back as payment compete = "NO"  if you want something different just adjust the case expression accordingly.